# Is there a way, using a possibly a chrome extension, to bring Chrome into focus in windows when a different app has focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Use case:

1) user has chrome open on my website (which, by the way, is an iframe from which I don't have security sandbox privileges to access the outer window).

2) user goes to different application; MS Word for example.

3) a js event fires on my website (rendered in an iframe) and should bring chrome into focus.  This is an internally-facing web app.

I tagged chrome-extensions because it seems like this should be possible:

1. google calendar already does exactly what is detailed above.
2. chrome.windows.update(windowId, {focused: true}) would do what I need... is there already a chrome extension that has hooks into this method?

Comment: You already asked about this yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26638158/934239 Instead of making a new question, it would be better if you edited your existing one with clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect switching from Chrome to another application, you can indeed use chrome.windows via a chrome extension.  Also, simple firing alert() will bring the browser application back into focus.

```
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(window) {
     if (window == chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_NONE) {
          // application lost focus
          alert('Don\'t leave me!');
     }
});
```

Comment: Very tempted to downvote due to the sheer evilness of this code! Well done.